reg_replace in PostgreSql with pattern matching
I have below dataset,
1. '{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}'
2. '{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}'
3. '{SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}'
3. '{SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}'

I need the result as,
1. {DATA,3015937}
2. {DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}
3. {DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}
4. {DATA,3015937}

Basically I wanted to replace SHEET followed by 7 digit number and extract only DATA followed by 7 digit number.
I tried using regexp_replace('{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}', 'SHEET,(\d\d\d\d\d\d\d),', '' ) the result of this is {SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}, as well as using similar to [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]
Finding difficulties to get the accurate result, any suggestion would be appreciated

Could something like '{SHEET,2730377,DATA,3015937,SHEET,5708283,DATA,0010965}', where there are two "DATA" pairs (or more than two separated by something else, be present? If so, what return value is desired?

Maybe REGEXP_REPLACE('{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}', '(DATA,[0-9]+,?)|.', '\1', 'g')?

@WiktorStribiżew, the OP wishes to preserve the braces.

Or, REGEXP_REPLACE('{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}', '^({)|(})$|(DATA,[0-9]+,?)|.', '\1\2\3', 'g')

If, as in the examples,

there are one or "DATA" pairs that are contiguous and are followed by "}' at the end of the string; and

there is at least one "STREET" pair that precedes the first "DATA" pair,


then you may convert matches of the following regular expression to empty strings:
^[^']*?'|{ '|(?:SHEET,\d{7},)+(?=DATA,\d{7}\b)|'$

Demo

I understand Postgres supports lookaheads.
The expression can be broken down as follows.
^                   # match the beginning of the string
  [^']*?            # match zero or more characters other than single 
                    # quotes, as few as possible        
  '                 # match a single quote
|                   # or
  { '               # match '{' followed by a space then a single quote 
|                   # or
  (?:               # begin a non-capture group 
    SHEET,\d{7},    # match 'SHEET' followed by a comma then 7 digits
                    # then a comma
  )+                # end non-capture group and execute it one or more times,
                    # as many as possible
  (?=               # begin a positive lookahead
    \bDATA,\d{7}\b  # match a word boundary then 'DATA,' then a comma
                    # then 7 digits then a word boundary
  )                 # end the positive lookahead
|                   # or
  '$                # match a single quote at the end of the string


Instead of REGEXP_REPLACEing what you want to remove, just SELECT what you want to extract as follows (all of the code below is available on the fiddle here):
CREATE TABLE t
(
  str TEXT NOT NULL
);

populate:
INSERT INTO t (str) VALUES
('{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}'),
('{SHEET,2730377,SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}'),
('{SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}'),
('{SHEET,5708283,DATA,3015937}');

and then we run the following:
SELECT
  '{' || ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_MATCHES(str, '(DATA,.*})+$', 'g'), ',') AS result
FROM
  t;

Result:
result
{DATA,3015937}
{DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}
{DATA,3015937,DATA,0010965}
{DATA,3015937}

Et voilà!
